# Is there a RPC library featuring USB support?

Tags: frameworks, usb, rpc

Suppose we want to talk to devices via Ethernet or USB using a high-level protocol. For example, we would like to inquire the model name of the device using a method

```c
    int device_get_model(char *model, size_t len);
```

Now of course one can implement a protocol, define message formats, and provide an abstraction layer that supports both Ethernet and USB. But then I believe that someone has already done something like this. But is there really a project like this?

There are plenty of code generators that generate high-level functions in any programming languages, and there are defined binary formats (protocol buffers, for example), which leads me to believe that one could combine existing projects to such a solution. However, the only thing missing is a message passing library that also provides USB support (TCP, UDP, websockets, IPC are routinely supported in many different projects, such as ZeroMQ). Is there a project that also supports USB?

Just to clarify, open-source is a must and platform independence would be nice, although Linux support would do for now.